# In Swift 4.2 - How can I maintain a sprite size after move(toParent: newParent)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When I am moving a sprite (an arrow in this case) from the one parent (the scene) to another parent (the target, which is a sprite in the scene) the arrow is being scaled and changes its size. How can I avoid it? I want the arrow to maintain its size.

This is the code I use when adding a new arrow to the scene:

```
func newArrow() {
    let arrow = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "arrow1")
    let arrowTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "arrow1")
    arrow.position = CGPoint.zero
    arrow.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: arrowTexture, size: arrowTexture.size())
    arrow.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    arrow.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    arrow.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    arrow.physicsBody?.friction = 0.2
    arrow.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.2
    arrow.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.1
    arrow.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    self.addChild(arrow)
}
```

And this is the code I use when I move the arrow to another parent:

```
func arrowCollideWithTarget() {
    arrow.move(toParent:target!)
}
```

Comment: The size of the child node is relative to the size of the parent node. If your new parent is smaller than your old parent, the child will also be smaller.

Comment: Thank you! How can I prevent it? I want the child to maintain its size.

Comment: The new parent would have to be the same size as the old parent. Or upscale the child node to create a sense of unchanged size. For instance, if parent 1 is 2x bigger than parent 2, increase the size of the child by 2 to avoid the shrinking..

Comment: Gotcha! thanks again!

Comment: @E.Huckabee That is not true at all.  Size and scale are two different things.  my guess is the reason why his arrow is changing size is because the scale of the target is not at 1.  You can have children larger than parents, and there are reasons to do so.

Comment: You were absolutely right! Thank you @KnightOfDragon! It saved me a bunch of time!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @E.Huckabee I was able to solve the problem. All I did was setting the scale of the target - You can do it in two ways:
1. Change the scale of the sprite in the 'Attributes inspector'
2. From code - sprite.xScale = 1.0 
               sprite.yScale = 1.0